# Can't compare user input to cell value in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

> I am trying to ask user input and compare the input to a column in my excel sheet. But I keep getting null and I can't get the compare value.

```
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename + ".xlsx")
sheet1 = wb.active
wb2 = xl.load_workbook("database.xlsx")
sheet2 = wb2.active
pn = input("Please enter PN: ")
col_B = sheet2['B']
for cell in col_B:
    if cell.value == pn:
        print(cell)
    else:
        print("null")
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the “break”. Otherwise it will stop the loop after the first cell being read.